# Extract all data from an API call using wildcard

Tags: rest

I am trying to extract organisation information from this open access REST API:

https://directory.spineservices.nhs.uk/ORD/2-0-0/organisations

The link to the documentation is [here](https://digital.nhs.uk/developer/api-catalogue/organisation-data-service-ord).

Effectively, you can access information for any organisation you like as in the example below, which returns the full dataset for the organisation with ODS code RJY:

https://directory.spineservices.nhs.uk/ORD/2-0-0/organisations/RJY

However, I don't want to extract information for specific organisations only and the first endpoint only returns a small subset of organisations.  Is there any way of using a wildcard to list the information for all the organisations?

Thanks.